# Extract Product Core Key Words With (Python) NLTK

Tags: python, search, nlp, nltk

After reading "Natural Language Processing With Python" for a day, I'm still not quite clear if NLTK can be used to extract core key words for human input product descriptions --

e.g., from this

```
Apple iPhone 4S (Latest Model) - 16GB - White or Black (Unlocked)
ANY GSM TMOBILE, AT&T, Home, Smartphone
```

to

```
Apple iPhone 4S 16GB Smartphone
```

or this

```
Canon EOS 5D 12.8 MP DSLR Camera with lens, vert grip & lots of extras
```

to

```
Canon EOS 5D 12.8 MP DSLR Camera
```

Any pointer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's ready-to-use function for this purpose in NLTK. You may need to write your own program calling the NLTK function. Key words matching or learning based on statistics may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are few other tools like [Maui-Indexer](https://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/), [Kea](http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/index.html) which you might be interested in this regard.